# How to get this backup batch to copy files back to different folders?

Tags: batch-file

**Current status at the bottom of the post.**

I'm not a programmer.  I realize this is probably super simple, but ive reached my limit.

I'm seeking a clean way (outside of listing each file to be copied back individually if possible) to take a file from a subfolder ***themes\Twilight.xml*** and back it up to the same "backup" folder the rest of the listed files are going to, then return it to its source folder.

Everything ive tried has resulted in everything from the themes folder ending up in the root/script directory creating a mess.

```
@echo off
title Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
echo Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
cd /d %~dp0
MD "backup"
echo.
for %%f in (config.xml, contextMenu.xml, langs.xml, shortcuts.xml, userDefineLang.xml) do copy "%~dp0\%%f" "backup"
echo.
echo Please do NOT close this window until you update Notepad++
echo.
echo Press any key AFTER updating to restore the backup files
echo.
pause
echo.
cd backup
copy *.xml "%~dp0"
cd /d %~dp0
echo.
del /s userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml
echo.
pause
```

to clarify - the script is being ran from within the root notepad++ directory. it creates a folder called backup and copies essential files from there to "backup" that are normally overwritten when portable N++ updates are extracted. after updating notepad++, advancing the script copies the files from "backup" back to their original location overwriting the "new/default" ones.

I'm struggling with getting the Twilight.xml moved from "themes" to "backup" and then back again to "themes" alongside all the others which are currently being backed up and restored properly to their proper location in the root of the notepad++ directory.

```
Notepad++ |- backup ------
          |
          |- themes ------ Twilight.xml
          |
          |- config.xml
          |
          |- session.xml
          |
          |- notepad++.exe
          |
          |- notepad++_backup_restore.bat
```

---


Currently stuck here, trying to find a way to get Twilight.xml & userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml back to their source folders (`themes` & `userDefineLangs` respectively) instead of to the root where the rest of the xmls are sent.

```
@echo off
title Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
echo Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
cd %~dp0
if not exist "backup" (MD "backup")
set files="config.xml";"contextMenu.xml";"langs.xml";"session.xml";"shortcuts.xml";"userDefineLang.xml";"themes\Twilight.xml";"userDefineLangs\userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml"
for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0%%~f" "%~dp0backup"
echo.
echo Please do NOT close this window until you update Notepad++
echo.
echo Press any key AFTER updating to restore the backup files
echo.
pause
echo.
cd backup
copy *.* "%~dp0"
cd %~dp0
echo.
pause
```

using the suggestion by neko of `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0" "%~dp0backup\%%~f"` (potentially incorrectly) to address this resulted in exponentially growing file sizes in my backup folder and thus in the root each time it was ran during testing.  It was not overwriting but adding-to each file somehow.

I attempted to use it in place of the original `for` as well as in addition to.  Also in place of the `copy` at the bottom modified to presumably (probably not due to my lack of understanding) copy from backup back to source locations by using `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0backup%%~f" "%~dp0\%%~f"` and variants.

Comment: Can you give more information of the filepaths? From your code it looks like you are copying files into a backup folder and then copying them back into their previous directory which would create duplicates of the files. It seems like you are mistaking `copy` with `move`

Comment: Also suggestion for cleanliness, instead of putting all of the files in that for command, you can put them into a variable each separated by a delimiter (my preference is a semicolon ;) and for the variable. : `set files=config.xml;contextMenu.xml;langs.xml;shortcuts.xml;userDefineLang.xml` and `for %%i in (%file%) do <whatever>`. Just my preference though

Comment: The `backup` folder is inside the `themes\` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```bat
@echo off
title Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
echo Backup Notepad++ Settings
echo.
cd %~dp0
if not exist "backup" (MD "backup")
echo.
set files="config.xml";"contextMenu.xml";"langs.xml";"shortcuts.xml";"userDefineLang.xml"
for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0%%~f" "%~dp0backup"
echo.
echo Please do NOT close this window until you update Notepad++
echo.
echo Press any key AFTER updating to restore the backup files
echo.
pause
echo.
cd backup
copy *.* "%~dp0"
cd %~dp0
echo.
del /s userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml
echo.
pause
```

Based on your code, this is all I can do. I am unsure on what you are trying to accomplish in certain parts of your code like `del /s userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml`, but I'll leave what to do with those up to you. If you also haven't noticed, I changed one of the final portions of the file `copy *.* "%~dp0"` to copy the backups back into the normal `notepad++` folder since I assume there will be more things to back up rather than only `xml` files. Also, if you want to also backup the `themes\Twilight.xml` file, you can just add it to the `%files%` variable by changing

```
set files="config.xml";"contextMenu.xml";"langs.xml";"shortcuts.xml";"userDefineLang.xml"
```

to

```
set files="config.xml";"contextMenu.xml";"langs.xml";"shortcuts.xml";"userDefineLang.xml";"themes\Twilight.xml"
```

**ERRORS IN YOUR CODE**

Overall, your code was good, but there were certain minor errors that I found.

1. For example, in your `for` loop, having a backslash (`\`) after `%~dp0` is redundant since by default `%~dp0` already has a backslash after the parent file path.
2. Having the `/d` switch after `cd` is also redundant since you are not changing drives.
3. Finally, you created another directory called `backups` in your script when you stated that it already exists.

If you have any questions with this answer, feel free to ask questions in the comments of this answer.

Comment: excellent answer.  I appreciate it! I've learned a bit more which is great. 
`del /s userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml` is present because that file causes issues with the theme i use so it was a quick way to make it disappear as its nested in a subfolder.

the only issue i see with your answer is the `twilight.xml`.  your way of adding it is perfect, but the blanket copy from the `backup` folder back to the `root`, will result in that file being copied back to the `root`.   How can i have it placed back where it came from in `themes`?

Comment: You can reuse the `%files%` variable and make another for loop that copies the files back to the `%~dp0` and since the `themes\twilight.xml` is already in the variable, it will copy back to the themes folder.

Comment: You can flip the existing for loop `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0%%~f" "%~dp0backup"` so it copies the files back to the directory like `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0" "%~dp0backup\%%~f"`

Comment: oh boy, i miffed something up.  toying with what you provided resulted in the copy somehow growing the files to exorbitant sizes.  it was merging them somehow.  So large i couldnt even open notepad++ by the time i noticed.  ha!

im pretty determined though.  the initial code you provided works perfectly, its just copying from backup back to where they came from as opposed to purely in the root.

Comment: seems its the addition of `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0" "%~dp0backup\%%~f"`

no matter where/how i try to shoehorn that in, it results in exponentially growing backed up files.

Comment: Do you want to move the whole backups folder back? instead of doing the variable, you can do the whole backup folder

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I accidentally flipped the 2 things in the copy command. Its actually `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0backup\%%~f" "%~dp0"`

Comment: ideally what would happen is i would close notepad++ and start the script which would copy the files in the files variable to a folder called backup (which it does)

i would extract the new update over top of everything.  I would then advance the script which would take everything in the backup folder and COPY it to the initial locations it backed them up from.

aka the majority would go to the root, and things like Twilight.xml would go back to the themes folder.

items in the backup folder would be left there as, you guessed it - backup :)

Comment: is `for %%f in (%files%) do copy "%~dp0backup\%%~f" "%~dp0"` intended to replace  `copy *.* "%~dp0"` ?
using it there does seem to return the files to the root, but i get `The system cannot find the path specified.` for the Twilight.xml

Comment: i dont know how to pick apart the Twilight.xml and now userDefinedLang-markdown.default.modern.xml which i have in the files variable and move them elsewhere.

I would need to set to do those two independently it seems like?

Comment: If you copied both themes folder and twilight.xml, It will work

Comment: never thought of that ha.  thank you for your time,  youve been very generous!